# How can I create a smooth scrolling animation for my navbar when scrolling down the page?

Tags: html, css, angular, styles, open-source

I have a navbar on my website that is supposed to smoothly collapse and shrink in size as the user scrolls down the page. However, instead of a smooth transition, the navbar simply disappears and is replaced with a smaller version. The same issue occurs with other elements on the page such as a dropdown menu.

Here is the css of the Regular version:

```
.opportunities-tab-customization-container[_ngcontent-gpm-c2] {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the css of the collapsed version:

```
.collapsed-opportunities-tab-customization-container[_ngcontent-gpm-c2] {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is the css of the animation and transition effect:

```
.translate-y[_ngcontent-gpm-c2] {
    -webkit-animation: translate-y 0.5s ease-out alternate;
    -moz-animation: translate-y 0.5s ease-out alternate;
    animation: translate-y 0.5s ease-out alternate;
}
```

I have tried adjusting the CSS of the navbar and the animation timing and easing, but I have not been able to achieve a smooth transition. I expected the navbar to smoothly collapse and the dropdown menu to smoothly transition as the user scrolls down the page.

```
.translate-y[_ngcontent-gpm-c2] {
    -webkit-animation: translate-y 0.5s ease-out alternate;
    -moz-animation: translate-y 0.5s ease-out alternate;
    animation: translate-y 1.5s ease-out alternate;
    height: 150px;
}
```

However, what actually happens is that the elements simply disappear and reappear without any smooth animation. As I scroll down from the top, the "Translate Text" heading and otter image get a bit smaller and the text below it fades out. Similarly for the dropdown on the right -- the idea is to make the translation smooth and not "one navbar replaced with another".

Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue? I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance in resolving this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using rxjs operator it's easy "hide" the nav (I imagine your nv has an height fixed of 60px)

There're a lot of examples in the web, but we are going to do in "Angular way" using rxkjs operator fromEvent and use pipeasync to subscribe

Imagine an html like

```
<nav [style.top]="scrollObs$|async">..your nav...</nav>
<div class="content">
     ..your content...
</div>
```

An .css

```
nav {
  background-color: #0074d9;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

We only need define our scrollObs$

```
scrollObs$ = fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
    map((_) => {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
         return '-60px';

      return '0';
    }),
    distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

If you don't want to hide else smaller, it's look like closer

```
nav {
  ...
  transition: height 0.3s; //<--see the height
}

<!--now we change the "style.height"-->
<nav [style.height]="scrollObs$|async">Hello nav</nav>

//Now we return 30px or 60px
scrollObs$ = fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
  map((_) => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
         return '30px'; //<--we change the height to 30px
    return '60px';   //the height normal
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqdrtc?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

**Update** Well it's a bit "hardcode" use [style.property], so.. why not use class

```
<!--now we change the "style.height"-->
<nav [class.collapsed]="scrollObs$|async">..your nav..</nav>

//Now we return 30px or 60px
scrollObs$ = fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(
  map((_) => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)
         return true;
    return null
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

Now, it's only define the class collapsed

```
nav.collapsed{
   height:30px;
}
```