# hello everyone, actually i need to create a complex navbar

Tags: html, css, angular

when user scolling, the element of navbar migrate to become a sidebar.
the very example of what I am trying to do is the navbar of this site:https://www.bechtle.com/fr-en

actually i create i responsive and simple navbar who don't satisfact  me

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search" style="margin-top: 16px;">
  <img src="/assets/connexion.jpg" alt="" class="position-absolute top-0 start-0" style="height:72px;width:72px; margin-top:16px;margin-left:16px;">

  <input class="form-control me-2" style="width:84rem; margin-right:16rem;height:36px;"  type="search" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your interest, in fact I would like to create a navbar which when a user scrolls the , this navbar reveals a pie chart and when you click on it a sidebar appears with all the information of the navbar. thank you for your comeback

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75455964/how-can-i-create-a-smooth-scrolling-animation-for-my-navbar-when-scrolling-down/75456922#75456922) to create a navbar to smooth size
2. Create two divs inside the navbar
3. use transformY or change the opacity of the divs insides "playing" with the class

happy coding :)